# C++ pointer to pointer to pointer multiplication not working

Tags: c++, pointers

This might be quite a simple question but anyways:
I'm using VS 2010 and what I want is to obtain the result of x****y at the end. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int x = 5;
    int *** y= new int**;
    ***y = 5;
    cout << x****y << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

This just makes the program crash and I can't figure out why.
This is the error log I get:

```
    1>------ Build started: Project: Stuffing around, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
    1>  main.cpp
    1>  LINK : D:\Programming Projects\Stuffing around\Debug\Stuffing around.exe not found or not built by the last incremental link; performing full link
    1>  Stuffing around.vcxproj -> D:\Programming Projects\Stuffing around\Debug\Stuffing around.exe
    ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Also, would there be a way to achieve the same results without dynamically allocating memory at **y? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You allocated a pointer to a pointer to an integer. But you haven't allocated the integer or the pointer to the integer.

Comment: Is that really an error log?

Comment: If you don't have a C++ book, get one and read the passage on pointers. If you do, well read the passage on pointers.

Comment: Would there be a way to achieve the same results without dynamically allocating memory at **y? Yes: `int y = 5;`

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, yeah, this is a contrived example, but what better way to learn how to play with pointers than experimentation for experimentation's sake? Play nice.

Comment: Yes, the whole point was to play around with multiple pointers. Glad the community here is so quick to help. I'm quite a beginner so I appreciate the snide remarks too :)

Comment: @antiduh - write real apps.  Shortly, pointers make sense.  Eventually, ** make sense.  Very, very occasionally, *** can be made to make sense.  **** should me made to be nonsense.

Comment: Without any dynamic allocation: `std::cout << 25 << '\n';` If you are not going to allocate memory, why use pointers at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is dynamically allocating a ptr to ptr to int, but not the nested ptr and int it would need to point to. (hope all the indirection made sense) To do this with dynamic memory your going to need something like this:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    void main()
    {
        int x = 5;
        int *** y= new int**;
        *y = new int *
        **y = new int
        ***y = 5;
        cout << x* (***y) << endl;
        system("pause");
    }
```

To do it without dynamically allocating memory you would need something like this:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    void main()
    {
        int x = 5;
        int y = 5;
        int *y_ptr = &y;
        int **y_ptr_ptr = &y_ptr;
        int ***y_ptr_ptr_ptr = &y_ptr_ptr;
        cout << x* (***y_ptr_ptr_ptr) << endl;
        system("pause");
    }
```

Comment: This is not valid C++. `main` should always return `int`.

Answer (score 2):

Without any dynamic allocation:

```
int x = 5;    
int i;
int *pi = &i;
int **ppi = &pi;
int ***y = &ppi;
***y = 5;
cout << x****y << endl;
```

You can't do it without either dynamic, static, or automatic allocation; a pointer needs something to point to.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer!

Answer (score 0):

Y is not initialized.

```
y = new int**;
*y = new int*;
**y = new int;
***y = 5;
```